# my query not working?

Tags: apex, soql, query, salesforce-id, pagination

I am querying the products from a particular price book as below.i want to select `product code`, `product name`, `product family` and `list price`.To show all these columns in my table.

```
(Select p.ProductCode, p.Name, p.Family, (Select UnitPrice From PricebookEntries) From Product2 p)
```

Comment: i want to correct myself that is not pricebook my query is on product and child pricebookentry

Comment: What error you are facing ???
at my end your query is working !!!

Comment: it is not showing the column of unit price or list price in a table

Comment: Can you paste your VF page code here, so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The Unit Price field is available in the list returned by the subquery. So your result is something like below:

> `ProductCode         Name             Family      PricebookEntries
>   SL9080      SLA: Platinum                    [{"UnitPrice":400}, "UnitPrice":400}]
>   GC3020      GenWatt Propane100kW             [{"UnitPrice":150},{"UnitPrice":150}]
>   GC3060      GenWatt Propane1500kW            [{"UnitPrice":120},{"UnitPrice":120}]`

Hence you would have to do something like - p.PricebookEntries[0].unitPrice, p.PricebookEntries[1].unitPrice and so on.

However a better approach would be to have a query other way round:

```
Select Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Product2.ProductCode, UnitPrice from PricebookEntry
```

This will give you results something like this:

```
Id                      Product2.Name           Product2.ProductCode        Product2.Family     UnitPrice
01u90000000h97SAAQ      SLA: Platinum           SL9080                                              400
01u90000000h97TAAQ      GenWatt Propane100kW    GC3020                                              150
01u90000000h97UAAQ      GenWatt Propane 1500kW  GC3060                                              120
```